# Using steganography to embed data in DWT subband coefficients

Tags: steganography, dwt

I have been doing more research on the topic of DWT Steganography. I have came across the code below   on the web. This is the first time I have came across subbands coefficients being specified. I have an idea what the code does but I would like someone to verify it!

```
steg_coeffs = [4, 4.75, 5.5, 6.25, 7];

for jj=1:size(message,2)+1
    if jj > size(message,2)
        charbits = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    else
        charbits = dec2bin(message(jj),8)';
        charbits = charbits(:)'-'0';
    end

    for ii=1:8
        bit_count = bit_count + 1;

        if charbits(ii) == 1
            if HH(bit_count) <= 0
                HH(bit_count) = steg_coeffs(randi(numel(steg_coeffs)));
            end
        else
            if HH(bit_count) >= 0
                HH(bit_count) = -1 * steg_coeffs(randi(numel(steg_coeffs)));
            end
        end
    end
```

I think the steg_coeffs are selected coeffiecnt of the HH subband, where bits will be embedded in these selected coefficients. I have googled randi and believe that it will randomise these specified coeffs on each iteration of the loop and embed in random selection coeffs. I am correct?? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing `help randi`, you find out that `randi(IMAX)` will return a scalar, which will be an integer uniformly distributed (based on a prng) in the range 1:IMAX. To put simply, it chooses a random integer between 1 and IMAX.

`numel(matrix)` returns the total number of elements in the matrix.

So, `steg_coeffs(randi(numel(steg_coeffs)))` chooses a random element from `steg_coeffs`, by choosing a random index between 1 and 5.

The embedding algorithm is implemented in the following block.

```
if charbits(ii) == 1
    ...
else
    ...
end
```

Basically, if you're embedding a 1, the `HH` coefficient has to be positive. If it isn't, substitute it with one from `steg_coeffs`. Similarly, if you're embedding a 0, the `HH` coefficient has to be negative. If it isn't, substitute it with the negative of one from `steg_coeffs`.

The idea is that when you extract the secret, all you have to check is whether the `HH` coefficient is positive or negative, to know whether the bit has to be 1 or 0.

Comment: Thank you Reti43. A very clear explanation as always :)

Comment: Hi Reti43. Just wondering when you say "by choosing a random index between 1 and 5" do you mean it could be anyone of steg_coeffs = [4, 4.75, 5.5, 6.25, 7]; or do you mean it could be 1,2,3,4,5. I am thinking it must be a random int from the array i.e 4.75, 6.25 etc but I just want to double check!thanks

Comment: The random index will be between 1 and 5. You then use that to access a specific elements of steg_coeffs, e.g. steg_coeffs(1) = 4, steg_coeffs(2) = 4.75, etc. So by choosing a random number between 1 and 5, you effectively choose a random element among 4, 4.75, 5.5, 6.25 and 7.

Comment: Hi,I have another query regarding the steg_coeffs. Why chose the coeffs from 4 to 7. From what I can gather,by looking at the HH coeffs in matlab, it is to do with a specific subband. I understand that all 4 subbands have different coeffs.If I was to chose HL for example, would the coeffs need to be different? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the subbands have different coefficients because they describe different information about the image. Why the code substitutes any coefficient, when it has to, with values between 4 and 7 can only be referenced by the intention of the code author, or the paper he based his code on. If I were to guess, I would say that the HH coefficients tend to have low values, so substituting them with other low values will not lead to extreme image distortions.